# Is there a word for this type of overhearing?

Tags: single-word-requests, conversation

just those snippets of conversations that you're not involved in that you overhear and its not even louder than the rest of their conversation it just stands out to you. I feel like that deserves an artsy vaguely pretentious word like on par with "wanderlust" a fancy pretty sounding word like that.

Comment: [selective hearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_auditory_attention) - *auditory attention is directed at things people are most interested in hearing.* Nearly everyone hears their own name more easily, for example, but there will be plenty of individual words/phrases that stand out to *you personally* as "significant" even though they might not be so to others.

Comment: I can't think of a noun, but perhaps you could say something like *"She pricked up her ears when she heard them discussing the burglary."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think your comment deserves to be an answer.

Comment: Super hearing ability of Superman.

Comment: John D. MacDonald used a phrase something like "growing hairy points on his ears"

Comment: "A man hears what he wants to hear and disregards the rest" (Paul Simon, from the song "The Boxer").

Comment: The reticular activating system (RAS) is considered the brain’s attention center. It is the key for switching on your brain and also considered as the main center of motivation. The skill to sluice out information brought out by the external sources and to pin point a particular fact with detailed thought is the controlled effect of the reticular activating system. (See http://www.innovateus.net/health/what-function-reticular-activating-system). Don

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a single word, but the correct phrase would be "selective hearing".

It's when your auditory system hears all the sounds and noise in the surrounding environment but only certain parts of the information are processed by the brain.

Similar to how when you learn about something and then suddenly see it everywhere (a type of bird for instance) it's because your brain recognizes it and latches onto that.  **There's so much information in the world - too much for your brain to process all of it - so your brain has to be selective and decide which information for you to notice.**

Every time you learn something, it creates a *link* in your brain.  When you learn it a second time, that link is strengthened.  These "brain links" make certain phrases or knowledge familiar and determine what stands out to you out of all the information your brain has to process.

Is that what you were asking?

EDIT: Selective hearing is also called '**Selective Auditory Attention**', which sounds a bit more pretentious/fancy like you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's commonly given a nefarious connotation, I think *Eavesdrop* would apply.

> eaves·drop /ˈēvzˌdräp/ verb
>
> secretly listen to a conversation

If you wanted to remove the connotation, you could further clarify it as "*unintentional eavesdropping*".

Answer (score 0):

"...his ears perked up" or a more colorful Yiddish variant, "... his ear grew fat."

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you try to include reference or link (that can support your answer) and its essential part? Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual word, but you could always say the bit of conversation "jumped out at you" or "your ears picked up what they were saying". Not sure if this helps, but I hope it did!